# Upload files to SharePoint using C#

Tags: development, file-upload

I'm trying to upload files to a folder using SharePoint and C#.

I managed to create folders with my code and it works fine.

This is my Document class:

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class Document
{
    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public bool ReplaceExisting { get; set; }

    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public string Folder { get; set; }

    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }

    public Document()
    {
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public Document(string name, byte[] content)
    {
        Name = name;
        ReplaceExisting = false;
        Content = content;
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public Document(string name, byte[] content, bool replace)
    {
        Name = name; 
        Content = content;
        ReplaceExisting = replace;
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
}
```

And this is the class where I use it to upload files (Document) to an existing SharePoint folder:

```
public class SharePointHandler : IDisposable
{
    private static string sharePointSite = "My Site";
    private static string documentLibraryName = "Root folder";

    public SharePointHandler() { }

    public void Upload(List<Document> documents, string company, int year, string quarter)
    {
        string Year = year.ToString();

        try
        {
            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(sharePointSite))
            {
                var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);
                context.Load(list);

                var root = list.RootFolder;
                context.Load(root);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                .
                .
                .

                foreach (var document in documents)
                {
                    var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
                    fileCreationInformation.Content = document.Content;

                    fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;

                    fileCreationInformation.Url = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + company + "/" + Year + "/" + quarter + "/" + document.Name;
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = quarterFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);


                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> property in document.Properties)
                        uploadFile.ListItemAllFields[property.Key] = property.Value;


                    try
                    {
                        uploadFile.CheckOut();
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
                    context.ExecuteQuery();

                    uploadFile.CheckIn("", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

When I run the code I have one document with:

Content: {byte[11430]}

Folder: null

Name: Testing.docx

Properties: Count = 0

ReplaceExisting: false

Everything works fine and I get the URL needed. But when I get to these commands:

```
try
{
    uploadFile.CheckOut();
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

The program fails and I get error that says: File not found.

Are there any detailed tutorials out there? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't forget you are using CSOM, it means quarterFolder.Files.Add just add the operation the requestBatch which will be executed when context.executQuery is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you are trying to check out the file before uploading the file itself. Try this first.

```
    fileCreationInformation.Url = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + company + "/" + Year + "/" + quarter + "/" + document.Name;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = quarterFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
    context.Load(fileCreationInformation);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
```